# Exploding string to array, then searching array for multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, search

**Background**

Users on a website can give their profile 'keywords', each separated with ', '. For example:

`green apples, bananas, red apples, pears`

This is stored in the database as a string.

I have a livesearch page where users can search for users by keyword. On this search, the page suggests keywords as the user types. For example, a user may type:

`apples`

and the page will suggest

`green apples`, `red apples`.

**Method**

When the input is sent to `keywordsearch.php`, the page searches the following:

```
$search_string_w = '%'.$search_string.'%';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `keywords` FROM `users` WHERE `keywords` LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(array($search_string_w));
while($results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result_array[] = $results;
}
```

This gets the row of the user who has the keyword. However, all I want to do is display each individual keyword as search suggestions, even if the keyword appears multiple times.

```
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {
        $keyw = explode(', ', $result['keywords']);
        $keyk = array_search($search_string, $keyw);
```

Now, `$keyw[$keyk]` will return a single keyword. So if the search is `apples`, this will only return `green apples` and not `red apples` too.

**Question**

How can I alter this code so that it returns all occurrences of the searched term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_search()` and `array_keys()` will only find `apple` given `apple`.  `preg_grep()` will give any of the entries containing `apple` such as `green apple`.

The `$result_array` can be searched as follows with `preg_grep()`:

```
$keyw = explode(', ', $result['keywords']);
//an array you can implode or loop through
$keyk = preg_grep("/$search_string/", $keyw);
// for case-insensitive use:  "/$search_string/i"
```

**Ideally you should have a keywords table with each keyword as its own row with related user id.**

Comment: Perfect - thanks. This is ideal. And you're right about having keywords in their own table - but the developer I'm working under doesn't seem to agree with me! Thanks again.